# Mysql select query slow down on large quantity of rows

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with 10 columns, It contains about 8 million rows. I'm doing a statistically job with this table. The problem is when I run more time, when id grows, the select query slow more.
Here is the query:

```
select * from transaction 
where id > :pointer
AND col_a = :col_a
AND col_b >= :from 
order by id ASC limit 5000
```

Both of 3 fields in the query have been created index.
After each loop, I will run query again with new pointer value, the value of pointer is `id` of last row of previous result set, I don't use `OFFSET`.
Finally, I took half of day to run the script with this query, too long.
So how can I fix this performance problem.

Comment: From which language / environment are you running your query?

Comment: Can you get rid of the LIMIT and move it to the WHERE clause like this: id > :pointer AND id <= :pointer  + 5000?

Comment: Do you have a chance to avoid the order by?

Comment: @Martin Perry In production, I run by PHP. But I don't think there's a language problem.

Comment: @TomaszMaciejewski I will try it, thanks :)

Comment: @Patrick Yes, I did that. Not problem with Order by

Answer (score 1):

> Both of 3 fields in the query have been created index

Mysql can use only one index per table in a query. If you created separate indexes for each field, then MySQL can use only one of them to speed up your query, not all 3.

I would create a multi-column index on `id, col_a, col_b` fields (in this order). This way a single index can be used to satisfy all 3 conditions in the `where` criteria and the `order by` as well.

> After each loop, I will run query again with new pointer value

Your code suggests that you use some kind of a parametrised query, but we cannot determine if it is a proper MySQL prepared statement. If it is not, then consider using MySQL prepared statement for this process.

Prepare the query before the loop and then in the loop just adjust the parameters and then execute the prepared statement again. This way MySQL will parse the query only once, not each time the code loops.

Comment: Thank for your response, but adding multi-column index makes no difference

Comment: Someone can likely assist if you could add SHOW CREATE TABLE transaction  AND include  SHOW INDEX FROM transaction.